# Get data from froala editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, wysiwyg, froala

Dont understand how get data from this editor. I read ofical documentation, but there they create new instance. I want send data from editor to my server. How i can do this. I still use Vue CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the text editor data simply by an event like this below's peace of codes:

```
new FroalaEditor('.selector', {
  events: {
    'contentChanged': function () {
      const editorContent = this.html.get();
      console.log(editorContent);
    }
  }
});
```

you can also find more on its [documentation](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events#contentChanged).

Comment: no i use form and now when i submit i use document.getElementByclass(.selector')['data-froala.editor'].html.get()

Comment: there is many ways that you can use, well done dude!